# Heroku can't find or load main class

Tags: java, heroku

I have a problem with heroku. I defined my Procfile and my pom.xml file as it was said in guide. But when I'm trying to launch my app after deploy on heroku or localy (command: sh target/bin/OPCBot).
 I recieve an error **Error: Could not find or load main class com.eiei.odessaportcheck.OdessaPortCheckApplication.**
How can I fix this?

This is my Procfile content:

```
worker: sh target/bin/OPCBot
```

And here is my code from pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.1</version>
     <configuration>
     <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
     <programs>
         <program>
              <mainClass>com.eiei.odessaportcheck.OdessaPortCheckApplication</mainClass>
              <name>OPCBot</name>
         </program>
     </programs>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>package</phase><goals><goal>assemble</goal></goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
```

P.S. I thik that problem lies in .bat file generated by appassembler-maven-plugin for heroku. When I try to launch it separately it says it can't find my main class.
I aslo tried:

```
<program>
     <mainClass>OdessaPortCheckApplication</mainClass>
     <name>OPCBot</name>
</program>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I messed up with a heroku tutorial. I should have used a tutorial for spring application instead of the regular one. After I have launched a project without spring, all was ok.